# Refresh non-index metadata in a Plone ZCatalog

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, archetypes

Zope catalogs contain catalog objects with *index* attributes (for use as query arguments) and *metadata* attributes (available when accessing the search result).  For index attributes, there is the possibility of reindexing for cases when the calculation logic of the index has changed.

I noticed that my `getThumbnailPath` *metadata* field was incorrect for one of my Archetypes-based content types. Of course, the metadata field contents don't change automatically when the method has changed; thus, I'd like to fix this in an upgrade step.

However, there seems to be no documented way to do this for metadata fields; the [catalog reindexing documentation](https://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/indexing.html#when-indexing-happens-and-how-to-reindex-manually) doesn't say much about this.

What would be the state-of-the-art way to do this?

- I there a way to refresh a certain metadata field?
- Do I need to do a catalog search for the affected type and reindex every single item (recalculating every other index and metadata field as well)?
- Should I create an index of the same name, and should I remove that index afterwards, or won't it matter anyway?

**Update**: For now, I chose the 2nd possibility, but it took ~ 100 seconds for the 1069 objects of that type, and it could easily take hours with all other objects affected as well; it would be nice to have a more selective way.

Comment: I posted a link to your question on the forum, https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-refresh-non-index-metadata-in-a-plone-zcatalog/4223 (but I see you already got a pretty definitive answer, yay!)

Comment: Cool, thank you! (Is this a privileged operation, or could I do this myself?)

Comment: Anyone is free to post to our forum. You can ask your questions directly there too. For a while it seemed fewer Plone people were answering questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The catalog metadata is updated whenever the object is indexed. I think the fastest way to update it is to reindex each object specifying a single index to update:

```
portal_catalog.catalog_object(obj, idxs=['getId'])
```

The time required will depend on how many objects and how many fields are included in the metadata.

(In other cases where you want to index *without* taking the time to update the catalog metadata, pass update_metadata=False to this same method.)

Comment: you can find an interesting thread on the topic in our community site: https://community.plone.org/t/best-practices-on-reindexing-the-catalog/4157?u=hvelarde